# how can change my webpage to any another website like browser

Tags: php

how can change my webpage to any another website like browser like this website
https://proxy.anonymster.com/browse.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com&b=15&f=norefer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iframe tag to embed another website within your page. For example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
```